# How do you avoid accidentally redeclaring a variable inside a code block in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and I came across this:

```
let mut x: i32 = 1;
x = 7;
let x = x; // x is now immutable and is bound to 7

let y = 4;
let y = "I can also be bound to text!"; // y is now of a different type
```

How can this be safe? Please check below:

```
let temp = 23;

// 200 lines of code

// I'm changing something here <====== IMPORTANT
let temp = 101;

// 200 lines of code

// do something with temp (with 23 not 101 !!!)
```

If I do `let temp = 101` again I have no way to know that I just created a nasty bug in the code. Do I really need to search for `let temp` before I type `let temp`? What am I missing?

Comment: I was going to say "your tests will cover logical errors like this" ... but then, if you have a 200 line function I imagine you're already having a hard time testing it properly... My answer would be: in practice, you don't run in to the issues you're thinking this causes often, if at all.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I'm coming from Java where that's exactly backwards! Meaning, once you declare `int x` in a scope you can't redeclare it. It makes sooo much sense that I must be missing something. It does not make sense to be scary every time you do `let x = 3;` because you might be erasing a value previously declared.

Comment: @rusty_programmer ...to which I would answer: `Java != Rust`. Thats like saying block scoping is backwards because Javascript has function-level scoping. I'm not sure what point you're trying to make there, sorry.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I honestly don't intend to create a language war. Just trying to understand how people proceed when they encounter this dilema, which is quite often in my experience.

Comment: @rusty_programmer The body of your question and your comments implies that you feel that shadowing is unsafe (and you're looking for explanations of how/why it might not be). Your title implies the opposite, which is why Shep changed it, but you changed it back. So which is it?

Comment: @rusty_programmer No problem. My question to you would be: How do you know you're about to override a variable in Java? The compiler I imagine throws an error for a re-declaration? You could leverage the Rust compiler too.. you could `temp = ();` .. and the compiler will tell you if it exists or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As another point, just to target the Java comparison and the "erasing" or "overwriting" prose being used, such as:

> It does not make sense to be scary every time you do let x = 3; because you might be erasing a value previously declared.

Rust still has scoping rules. The shadowing respects the scopes. Unlike Java, you can shadow the variable but it preserves the scope of the original. [For example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=05c9a851616f9f81541c68b7f0698037&version=stable&backtrace=0):

```
fn main() {
    let x = 3;

    {
        let x = 5;

        println!("Inner scope: {}", x); // Prints 5
    }

    println!("Outer scope: {}", x); // Prints 3
}
```

The shadowing takes scope into account.

Comment: Although adding scope just to prevent that feels overkill.

Comment: @rusty_programmer Sure, in this tiny example. Larger bodies of code (especially your example of a 200 line function) generally have some nested scopes. My point was to demonstrate that it is called shadowing because it "shadows".. it certainly does not overwrite or erase anything.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I like this idea a lot. However, I think it would be really clever if there was some way of giving a name to these scopes, to make it easier to understand what they do. I've also occasionally had to copy and paste these scopes to reuse them, which was a real pain. I wonder if we could add something to solve that too. Even rarer, I've had scopes that repeated the same logic, but using different variable names. That was really tricky to copy and paste and get right. It's a good thing I'm paid by the line! 

Comment: Neither of the answers explain a solid reason for this feature and just do "you're holding the phone wrong"

Comment: The question doesn't ask us to provide a reason for this feature @DMin. The question quite specifically asked "what am I missing?" about this feature. I provided an answer to one of the more obvious things the OP was missing. If you're looking for a reason why _Rust_ specifically allows it ... well, its likely because [all of the languages it takes inspiration from also allow it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't Rust, or any programming language really, it's the code. Specifically this "line":

```
// 200 lines of code
```

If you write 200 (or 400!) lines of code between the declaration of a variable and a usage of it, it's very likely that something unexpected will happen. However, whatever that is could also happen if the variable is mutable and you change it accidentally:

```
let mut a = 1;
a += 1;
// or
let a = 1;
let a = 2;
```

Both of those have the same end result, but only one of them involves shadowing.

Personally, I find shadowing very useful with Rust's wrapper types like `Option` or `Result`:

```
fn foo(name: Option<&str>) {
    let name = name.unwrap_or("Who are you");
    println!("{}", name);
}
```

If you find that you are not able to handle variable shadowing, then I'd suggest looking into [Clippy](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy), which has multiple `shadow_*` lints that you can turn on and disallow your code from compiling if you have any shadowing.

> Sometimes you are changing someone else's code. I have no way to know that `a` is already being used. How do I pick a variable name then?

I'd suggest that you *read the code* before modifying it. Some editors also allow searching through text for patterns or highlighting patterns.

> I'm coming from Java where that's exactly backwards! Meaning, once you declare `int x` in a scope you can't redeclare it.

That's true, but you can still shadow your instance or class variables:

```java
public class HelloWorld {
  static int a = 42;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 21;
    System.out.print(a); // Oh no, it's not 42 anymore!
  }
}
```

The Java compiler doesn't prevent this mistake; it's up to you, your tests, your code review, or external linting tools.

> How do you avoid accidentally redeclaring a variable inside a code block in Rust?

You could have a small piece of paper next to your desk. Write the number zero on it. Every time you declare a new variable, you add one to the number. Prefix or suffix all your variables with that number.

To be on the safe side, you could also add your name to the variable - you wouldn't want to conflict with anyone else following the same algorithm. You may also want to add the function and type to the name of the variable, to avoid clashes between different functions.

Of course, these variable names might be very long. To fix that, you might want to abbreviate all of the above, and write the number as either hexadecimal or maybe Base64. Instead of `my_type_cool_function_john_doe_x_12223123`, you can have the fairly unique `mtcfjdxBA8293`. This is very unlikely to collide with any existing variables.

<sub>(The above is satire)</sub>

---

Make no mistake: I **strongly** believe that the problem is **not** variable shadowing: it's functions that are hundreds of lines long which require so much mental overhead. Create functions, create types and methods on those types, but somehow fix the code before changing it further for the worse.

Comment: Sometimes you are changing someone else's code. I have **no way to know** that `a` is already being used. How do I pick a variable name then?

Comment: @rusty_programmer Be more descriptive in how you name variables. Don't name so many things with only a single letter. `x` may be easier to type the first time, but doesn't provide any real context about the value or intended use, making maintenance more difficult (e.g. collisions and shadowing are more likely – *hint*). Spend the extra time now adding clarity to save time later.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Even being descriptive there's a chance it was used before in the same code block.

Comment: @rusty_programmer if your function is so long that you can't fit it all on a screen or two, you probably need to refactor it.

Answer (score 3):

Any variable that has a lifetime that covers 100s of lines of code should have a long and descriptive name, and generally should never shadow.

Names like `temp` and `x` should only be used for variables with *short* lifetimes -- a dozen lines or less -- so that for any use of the variable, you can easily see the definition of it a few lines earlier.

Comment: If you are changing someone else's code and want to introduce a new variable how can you be sure you are not overriding a previous declared variable?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a method that is hundreds of lines long and you want to introduce a new variable, I would suggest that instead of adding more variables to a long method, you call a function instead in the spot where you would want to introduce a new variable. Then you get two advantages: a new scope where you know your variable isn't shadowing or being shadowed, plus you're not adding code to an already long method.

Comment: I like this too - "Don't leave broken windows". Adding code to a huge function is breaking the window further.